# Google Script insertSheet not accepting string object?

Tags: google-apps-script

So I am taking data from a spreadsheet, putting the relevant parts into an array and writing it back to a new spreadsheet. The data is coming from a google form and not everyone had an input for every question so I am taking only the questions that are not null. Which causes the length of my array to be variable

So I have taken it down to its most barest steps and I am stuck at the part where you insert the sheet, it works fine on a iteration of 1, but when I do it on a loop there is an error.

```
    for (j=2; j <= 3 ; j++)// I have 23 iterations, but I stopped at 2 for now
    {

      var cellLocation = new String ("B" + j + ":AC" + j);
      Logger.log("J is " + j + "Cell location " + cellLocation);
      var workingRange = buySheet.getRange(cellLocation);
      var customer = workingRange.getValues(); //this produces a range of the row
      Logger.log("Range is " + workingRange.getA1Notation() + " data is " + customer[0][0]); 
    //At first I thought it was the range- so I broke everything out into the tiniest step 

    var nameCustomer = new String(customer[0][0]);
    Logger.log("nameCustomer is " + nameCustomer);
    //this correctly prints out the names as strings- through 23 iterations
    var create = buySheet.insertSheet(nameCustomer); 
   //this is a sheet object with the customers name- fails after the first iteration, and creates sheets with blank names -
}
```

This is the reference I am using: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertSheet(String)

I have commented out everything after this to solve this one sticking point. I have tried instantiating the string outside the loop. I can post the logs, I am using real data I have so I would have to blur out peoples names.

It works for the first round, and it works if I manually type a string.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! When I created a new sheet it moved the active sheet to the new sheet. So at the end of the loop I have to reset the active sheet to the first sheet where the data I want it is.

Seems so obvious in retrospect.